# Dock ActiveX object and make it take up all the free space constantly

Tags: javascript, html, object, activex

I have something like this:

```
<OBJECT id='MyObject' name='MyObject' classid='clsid:2C582098-28CA-224e-D9B9-34E516F10E9F' width='...' height='...'>
```

I was determining by myself using javascript the width and the height of the page in order to automatically resize the object everytime the browser's window changes its size. However, is it possible to "dock" the object in the page? I mean, just make the object take all free space on the page for every moment available?

Thanks in advance.

Zubrowka

Comment: try setting the width/height to 100%, and css body{margin:0}

Comment: damn, i feel really stupid! thanks @david! (please answer my question, i'll accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try setting the `width/height` to 100% on the object and the `body` css margin to 0

Comment: Another common trick is to put the object tag in a div using width/height to 100% and then use CSS to position that; if you only have the activex control in the document then you can just do this with the body, of course.